# Flutter QR Scan is not working after Camera Tab

Tags: android, flutter, dart, qr-code

My app has 2 bottom tabs first one is to capture an Image and second one is to scan QR code through camera.

for Camera i'm using camera: ^0.9.4+1 plugin and for QR code its scan: ^1.4.3 https://pub.dev/packages/scan

once app is restarted you can tap on QR code tab its working then tab on Camera its working too now again tapping on QR tab it shows some wired errors it seems camera not properly disposed or any thing.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:snapi/controllers/home/home.controller.dart';

class CaptureTab extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<CameraDescription> cameras;

  const CaptureTab({Key? key, required this.cameras}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CaptureTabState createState() => _CaptureTabState();
}

class _CaptureTabState extends State<CaptureTab> {
  Size size = Get.size;
  final HomeController controller = Get.find();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeCamera(0);
  }

  late CameraController _controller; //To control the camera
  late Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;
  List<File> capturedImages = [];

  initializeCamera(int cameraIndex) async {
    _controller = CameraController(
      widget.cameras[cameraIndex],
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
    );

    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = Get.size;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: size.height - size.height * 0.076,
            child: FutureBuilder<void>(
              future: _initializeControllerFuture,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return CameraPreview(_controller);
                } else {
                  return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

QR code scanning code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:scan/scan.dart';
import 'package:snapi/controllers/home/home.controller.dart';

class ResourceTab extends StatefulWidget {
  const ResourceTab({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ResourceTabState();
}

class _ResourceTabState extends State<ResourceTab> {
  String _platformVersion = 'Unknown';
  final HomeController homeController = Get.find();

  ScanController controller = ScanController();
  String qrcode = 'Unknown';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initPlatformState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: ScanView(
              controller: controller,
              scanAreaScale: .7,
              scanLineColor: Colors.green.shade400,
              onCapture: (data) async {
                // do something interesting
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> initPlatformState() async {
    String platformVersion;
    try {
      platformVersion = await Scan.platformVersion;
    } on PlatformException {
      platformVersion = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }
    if (!mounted) return;

    setState(() {
      _platformVersion = platformVersion;
    });
  }
}
```

The best explanation of error is look like this.

this is the error i got while opning QR scaning view after Camera preview.

E/CameraCaptureSession( 7546): Session 0: Exception while stopping repeating:

android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): cancelRequest:459: Camera 0: Error clearing streaming request: Function not implemented (-38)

[image]

Comment: Could you share how your tabs are implemented? Is dispose method really being called?

Comment: manually changing tabs with Switch through getx controller